# What could cause a sudden influx of unfiltered spam email?

Tags: spam

Waking up this morning, I found a large number of spam emails in my outlook inbox. Typically I never see *any* spam in the inbox, as it is almost always successfully filtered. Even in the junk box I only typically receive 4-5 emails on a bad day.

These emails started coming in while I was asleep and continued for 8 hours, at which point they stopped abruptly. You can see the exact times (BST) and nature of the emails in the picture below.

[image]

What could be the cause of this temporary large influx of unfiltered spam emails?

Comment: Perhaps your ISP's spam filter was off for a few hours?  But really, we can't possibly know why.  All we can do is guess, which isn't really going to help you or anyone else.

Comment: That might be the case, but I wouldn't know that ahead of time (i.e. without asking the question) and there may be some kinds of responses that are actionable.

Answer (score 2):

The most reasonable explanation is that your email address recently ended up in a email list used by spammers.

How could this happen? There are at least three possibilities:

1. you recently subscribed to a website, who secretly "shared" email addresses with shady organizations;
2. you subscribed (perhaps a long time ago) to a website which was recently breached, and the resulting email/password dump circulated in underground communities;
3. someone directly gave your email address to spammers, as a prank. Unfortunately, there are individuals and websites devoted to this ridiculous activity.

Comment: Some of the commenters on [this post](https://www.troyhunt.com/dating-the-ginormous-myspace-breach/) by Troy Hunt mention getting an influx of spam related to the recent MySpace breach. Coincidence? I think not.

Comment: Thank you, though I wonder, does this explain the unfiltered part of the question too?

Comment: @Nytik I guess not. Spam emails don't get filtered or unfiltered because of the source of the "leak", so to say. It has a lot more to do with writing more sophisticated emails which don't trigger the spam alerts or, as John Deters suggested in a previous comment, with a possible downtime of your ISP spam filter.